# How do I send raw ftp command?

Tags: ftp

I have a situation that I have to use raw ftp commands such as cwd, retr, size, stor, type, and rest. I found out that most of GUI based FTP clients do not support command line commands.

Is there a window ftp client that supports raw ftp commands?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

many clients have a way to *quote* input commands and send them directly to the server.

For example, with the Windows command-line client (ftp.exe), log on to a remote host and try this:

```
ftp> quote cwd /pub
250 OK. Current directory is /pub
ftp> quote mode s
200 S OK
```

..and so on.

GUI clients typically have a similar function. FlashFXP has the Raw Command (CTRL-R) menu option for example.

Answer (score 0):

Open a command prompt and type ftp press 'enter'.  This will give you an ftp command prompt. Type help for available commands.

This should work on most versions of Windows, from 2000 on.